# Arrow Left at the Back of the Card won't return for Mobile and Desktop

Tags: css

How do you make the card to transform back to the front card when you click on the return arrow left icon at the back of this card both on mobile and desktop device. https://jsfiddle.net/86pkrs4v/. I tried using the ff breakpoints but it won't transform. I still wan't the hover to be applied in desktop and on mobile you can click anywhere of the front card to apply the transform styling.

```
@media (min-width:1025px)  {
.more {
 display: none;
 }
.card:hover  .content {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }
}

@media only screen 
 and (min-device-width : 320px) 
 and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
 .more {
  display: none;
  }
 .more:checked ~ .content {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) !important;
  }
 .card:hover .content {
 transform: rotateY(180deg) !important;
 }
 }
```

Comment: If you have the rotate on hover why you need a button to rotate it back ? just let the user unhover

Comment: I need it for mobile, because you can't hover it and you need to click it for return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the following javascript:

```
$(".card").click(function(e){
    $(".card").addClass("myclass");
});
$(".card").mouseout(function(e){
    $(".card").removeClass("myclass");
})
```

and the class in css:

```
.myclass .content{
  transform: rotateY(0deg)!important;
}
```

in this example you can click anywhere on the card to make the rotation back to 0 degrees, but you can change it to

```
$(".button").click(function(e){ ...
```

if you only want the arrow to be clickable.

Comment: Hi!, I followed your suggestion and applied this on the actual site https://www.besocialscene.com/new-sept-homepage?hs_preview=YhTtsyAc-13258353405, I think something is off when you click on the return arrow you need to click it twice for it to return and on mobile it is not working,

Comment: Actually it is now working, I just need to separate the actions on each of the card, since when you click one card the action seems to follow on the other cards

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution if you want then you can put some contents as per your requirement inside the `card`

```js
var card = document.querySelector('.card');
card.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
});
```

```css
.scene {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  margin: 40px 0;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.card.is-flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card__face--front {
  background: red;
}

.card__face--back {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="scene scene--card">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__face card__face--front">front</div>
    <div class="card__face card__face--back">back</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

edit or preview [Here on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n72m4zqo/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, clicking on arrow you want it to behave same as when you remove mouse away from `<div class="content">`.

If so, there are two things:

1. make it `transform: rotateY(0deg)`, not 180 since it is already rotated for 180 degrees and we want it to turn back.
2. Clean it up for hover to work and let css work as before.

I think, the simplest solution is

```
let backArrowLeft = document.querySelector(".button.return");
let flipContent = document.querySelector(".content");

backArrowLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
    flipContent.style = "transform: rotateY(0deg);";
});

flipContent.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    this.style = "";
});
```

To make it easier to maintain, you can create class and add/remove it on those two events, similar to Joachim's answer, I just post it since I've seen on fiddle that you don't use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Let's mark the discover button first:

```
                        <label for="card1" class="button discover" aria-hidden="true">
                          Discover
                        </label>
```

You can add the following in the javascript. Note that a click on mobile will also activate the hover trigger, so we don't just want to toggle based on a click on the button:

```
$(".return").click(function(e){
    $(".card").addClass("turned");
});

$(".discover").click(function(e){
  $(".card").removeClass("turned");
});
```

Then, replace in the CSS the transformation:

```
.card:not(.turned):hover .content {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card.turned .content {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card.turned:hover .content {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

Comment: this one works but when I tried to use the card2 the card1 also flips.

Comment: Then you're probably able to modify the selectors to select only the specific card, you can try!